# Django - sitemap file from google. How to serve this up?

Tags: python, django, apache

So here is the problem. I have never used Django before but our company took over SEO for a site that was built with Django. I have sftp access to the site and cms login information. (we are not hosting this)

I have a few questions: Do i need to install any software locally on my machine for any reason to modify the website? What I am talking about is a CLI or anything like that? (of course I have my IDE of choice - phpstorm)

I am brand new to Django (and python) - this is my exposure and from my understanding there is typically a build process with Django - such as a dev staging and production site. I of course do not have a build process so I am working off of production. Is this even feasible with Django?

The pressing issue is our SEO team wants me to replace the sitemap with one generated from the google search console. I have read through the Django documentation and I learned that the sitemaps are being generated through a class of some sort. See:

```
# urls.py
from django.contrib.sitemaps import FlatPageSitemap, GenericSitemap

# Sitemap config
pages_sitemap = {'queryset': Page.objects.filter(status='active'), 'date_field': 'modified'}
news_sitemap = {'queryset': Article.objects.filter(status='active'), 'date_field': 'modified'}
blog_sitemap = {'queryset': Post.objects.filter(status='active'), 'date_field': 'modified'}
events_sitemap = {'queryset': Event.objects.filter(status='active'), 'date_field': 'modified'}
success_stories_sitemap = {'queryset': SuccessStory.objects.filter(status='active'), 'date_field': 'modified'}
videos_sitemap = {'queryset': Video.objects.filter(status='active'), 'date_field': 'modified'}
aos_sitemap = {'queryset': AreaOfStudy.objects.filter(status='active'), 'date_field': 'modified'}
facilities_sitemap = {'queryset': Facility.objects.filter(status='active'), 'date_field': 'modified'}

sitemaps = {
    'pages': GenericSitemap(pages_sitemap, priority=1.0),
    'news': GenericSitemap(news_sitemap, priority=0.9),
    'blog': GenericSitemap(blog_sitemap, priority=0.9),
    'events': GenericSitemap(events_sitemap, priority=0.9),
    'success_stories': GenericSitemap(success_stories_sitemap, priority=0.5),
    'videos': GenericSitemap(videos_sitemap, priority=0.6),
    'areas': GenericSitemap(aos_sitemap, priority=0.8),
    'facilities': GenericSitemap(facilities_sitemap, priority=0.8),
}


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # sitemap.xml
    (r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
    # TinyMCE
    (r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    # Uncomment the next lines to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include('log_viewer.admin_urls')),
    url(r'', include('log_viewer.urls')),
    (r'^admin/filebrowser/', include('filebrowser.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

*I am considering using an apache directive to bypass this - but i am not sure if that is a good idea or if it will even work?*

**How do i replace the sitemap to be a static file instead of being generated on request?**

Thanks!

Comment: My advice would be _not_ to use a static file. Instead, determine what is desirable about the static file you have and then get Django to generate a file with those attributes.

Comment: @Chris well the sitemap being generated is not right. See: https://www.westerntech.edu/sitemap.xml

Comment: In that case the question I'd be asking is how to _fix_ the existing sitemap feature, not how to throw it away.

Comment: @Chris - sure that would be a better approach. For for a quick patch until it is fixed we thought it would be quicker to serve a static file. Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got the static site map uploaded and the path is www.mydomian.com/static/sitemap.xml and we are updating the google search console to look there instead of the default location.

Thanks for looking!